# Assign data from another sheet based on ID

Tags: excel

I have two MS Excel sheets with data formatted as follows:

Sheet 1:

```
Num ID
1   A
2   D
3   B
4   A
5   A
6   C
7   D
```

Sheet 2:

```
ID  data1   data2
A   A1      A2
B   B1      B2
C   C1      C2
D   D1      D2
…   …       …
```

I'm trying to add values from sheet 2, columns data1 and data2 into sheet 1 such that the values for each row corresponds with the matching ID.
E.g.

```
Num ID  data1   data2
1   A   A1      A2
2   D   D1      D2
3   B   B1      B2
…   …   …       …
```

etc.

Thank you.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `VLOOKUP` function twice here.  First format your sheet 2 as follows:

```
  A   B      C   D
1 ID  data1  ID  data2
2 A   A1     A   A2
3 B   B1     B   B2
4 C   C1     C   C2
5 D   D1     D   D2
…   …       …
```

Here is your sheet 1 with labels:

```
  A   B
1 Num ID
2 1   A
3 2   D
4 3   B
5 4   A
6 5   A
7 6   C
8 7   D
```

Then enter the following formula into column c of sheet 1 for `data1`:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!A2:B5, 2, FALSE)
```

Do the same also for `data2`:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!C2:D5, 2, FALSE)
```